# Accessing BeautifulSoup elements in django template

Tags: python, xml, django, django-templates, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to display the results of a SOAP request in a django template.

The results are in xml so I've used BeautifulSoup to process the data and would like to access the BeautifulSoup object in my django template, looping through each element and calling their child elements by name like so

```
{% for item in bs_data %}
    {{ item.child1.text }} {{ item.child2.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can do this in python, however my django template seems to treat the BeautifulSoup elements as if they have no children, although it will loop through the items in bs_data item.child1 is empty as is item.0

I can't even iterate through the sub elements of each element.

I've looped through the elements in my view and created nested lists to achieve the same result but if anyone knows how to persuade the django template to parse the Beautiful Soup objects I'm dying to know.

EDIT

OK So with the below example xml I can print the different elements and step through the elements printing the text. The below code:

```
b = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup("<note>\
    <to>Tove</to>\
    <from>Jani</from>\
    <heading>Reminder</heading>\
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\
    </note>")

print b.to

print b.body

for i in b:
    print i.text
```

Results in the below output:

```
<to>Tove</to>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
ToveJaniReminderDon't forget me this weekend!
```

However I can't replicate this in the django template with b passed into the template as it was in the python code above

Template code:

```
{{ b.to }}
{{ b.body }}
{% for i in b %}
    {% i.text %}
{% endfor %}
```

Results in nothing, however the following:

```
{{ b }}
```

shows the BeautifulSoup object

Comment: Do you have an example of `bs_data` that is failing.

Comment: it's not failing the for loop above would just result in empty lines in the html

Comment: If you don't provide example data, you're making it harder for people to help you, which might explain why you haven't got any answers.

Comment: It looks the object looses its nature. Try to access those values using `b['body']` and let us know if works.